# Different Results from Simplify, dependent on explicit vs computed rules

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Can anybody explain why these two pieces of code are giving me different results?

Heres the inputs:

```
eq1 = f[v3, w3] == a1 c1 f[v1, w1] + a1 c2 f[v1, w2] + a2 c1 f[v2, w1] + a2 c2 f[v2, w2];
eq2 = f[v4, w4] == b1 d1 f[v1, w1] + b1 d2 f[v1, w2] + b2 d1 f[v2, w1] + b2 d2 f[v2, w2];


eq3 = Simplify[eq1, a1 c2 b2 d1 == a2 c1 b1 d2]
eq4 = Simplify[eq2, a1 c2 b2 d1 == a2 c1 b1 d2]
```

And here are the two expressions

```
expr = b1 d2 f[v3, w3] - a1 c2 f[v4, w4];
Simplify[
 expr /. {
  f[v3, w3] -> a1 c1 f[v1, w1] + a1 c2 f[v1, w2] + a2 c1 f[v2, w1] + a2 c2 f[v2, w2],
  f[v4, w4] -> b1 d1 f[v1, w1] + b1 d2 f[v1, w2] + b2 d1 f[v2, w1] + b2 d2 f[v2, w2]}]

expr = b1 d2 f[v3, w3] - a1 c2 f[v4, w4];
Simplify[
 expr /. {
  Map[Reverse, ToRules[eq3]],
  Map[Reverse, ToRules[eq4]]}]
```

Heres the output:

```
a1 b1 (-c2 d1 + c1 d2) f[v1, w1] + (-a1 b2 c2 d1 + a2 b1 c1 d2) f[v2,w1] + (a2 b1 - a1 b2) c2 d2 f[v2, w2]

{b1 d2 (a1 c1 f[v1, w1] + a1 c2 f[v1, w2] + a2 c1 f[v2, w1] + a2 c2 f[v2, w2]) - a1 c2 f[v4,w4], -a1 c2 (b1 d1 f[v1, w1] + b1 d2 f[v1, w2] + b2 d1 f[v2,w1] +b2 d2 f[v2, w2]) + b1 d2 f[v3, w3]}
```

This is especially strange considering the output of the `Map[Reverse, ToRules[eqx]]` results in the same expression as the code in the first block.

The second piece of code also seems to return a single item list, whereas the second does not.

Any clues?

Comment: what are the definitions of eq3 and eq4?

Comment: `eq3 = Simplify[eq1, a1 c2 b2 d1 == a2 c1 b1 d2]
eq4 = Simplify[eq2, a1 c2 b2 d1 == a2 c1 b1 d2]` And the eq1 and 2 are more of the same, with functions multiplied by constants

Comment: I would've made a MWE but I think if you ignore the long polynomials it's fairly minimal

Comment: I am sorry, but you have to specify eq1 and eq2 as well. Otherwise you're asking us why one expression replacement differs from another one with unknown replacements.

Comment: Sure, I see what you're saying. I've edited the question to state the explicit input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between both results is caused by a subtle difference in the inputs.

The first replacement has a simple list of replacement rules:

```
expr /. {
  f[v3, w3] -> a1 c1 f[v1, w1] + a1 c2 f[v1, w2] + a2 c1 f[v2, w1] + a2 c2 f[v2, w2],
  f[v4, w4] -> b1 d1 f[v1, w1] + b1 d2 f[v1, w2] + b2 d1 f[v2, w1] + b2 d2 f[v2, w2]}
```

The second replacement is almost the same except that it contains a second set of curly braces, generated by your `Map` operations:

```
expr /. {
      {f[v3, w3] -> a1 c1 f[v1, w1] + a1 c2 f[v1, w2] + a2 c1 f[v2, w1] + a2 c2 f[v2, w2]},
      {f[v4, w4] -> b1 d1 f[v1, w1] + b1 d2 f[v1, w2] + b2 d1 f[v2, w1] + b2 d2 f[v2, w2]}}
```

This use or `ReplaceAll` is actually not documented. The help page will show you that the replacements are specified either by a simple rule or a list of rules. In your 2nd replacement, you have a list consisting of two lists of rules. So, it's a case of

```
a + b /. {a -> c, b -> d}
(* c + d *)
```

vs

```
a + b /. {{a -> c}, {b -> d}}
(* {b + c, a + d} *)
```

As you can see, this undocumented version of `ReplaceAll` effectively returns a list of replaced expressions, one for every replacement list.

The second replacement needs a `Flatten` to be equivalent to the first one

Comment: Thanks! as a follow up question, Is there a way to make the map function produce a single list?

Comment: Map produces a single list, but you have put two of them in a list, so, as I said in my answer, you have to use Flatten to make it a single one.

Comment: Yeah I did that. I was just wondering if there was a way to use a single map function to make two rules. Something like `Map[{{Reverse, ToRules[1]},{Reverse, ToRules[2]}}]` I suppose even writing that, I can see why that might not be possible.

Comment: @AlexDB What about `#2 -> #1 & @@@ {eq3, eq4}`?